# Como adicionar incremento a cada ID e zerar após um novo <div> PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Quero saber quantas linhas tenho em cada  e qual linha será modificada, para isso quero adicionar incremento no `id="id_tec_pag'+id_tec_pag+'[]"`. E que a cada mudança de bloco esse contador reinicie.

Corpo:

```
            html += '                           <tbody>';               
            html += '                               <tr class="linhas'+cdRegiao+'">';
            html += '                                   <input type="hidden" id="id_tec_pag'+id_tec_pag+'[]"/>';
            html += '                                   <td class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="nome'+cdRegiao+'_tec[]"/></td>';
            html += '                                   <td class="col-md-3"><input type="text" name="email'+cdRegiao+'_tec[]"/></td>';
            html += '                                   <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" name="telefone'+cdRegiao+'_tec[]"/></td>';
            html += '                                   <td class="col-md-2"><input type="password" name="senha1'+cdRegiao+'_tec[]"/></td>';
            html += '                                   <td class="col-md-2"><input type="password" name="senha2'+cdRegiao+'_tec[]"></td>';
            html += '                                   <td class="col-md-1"><button type="button" class="removerCampo"><i class="fa fa-close fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?=TXT_BOTAO_EXCLUIR?></button></td>';
            html += '                               </tr>';
            html += '                           </tbody>';
            html += '                       </table>';
            html += '                   </div>';
            html += '                   </div>';

            $('#div-regioes').append(html);

            adicionaCampo(cdRegiao);
```

JS:

```
    function adicionaCampo(codigo) {
        //$(".adicionarCampo").unbind("click");
        $(".adicionarCampo").on("click", function () {
            novoCampo = $("tr.linhas"+codigo+":first").clone();
            novoCampo.find("input").val("");
            novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas"+codigo+":last");
            removeCampo(codigo);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Você qual o index (numero da linha) ou o id que está na linha?

Comment: Tente mudar `<input type="hidden" id="id_tec_pag'+id_tec_pag+'[]"/>';` para `<td style='display: none' class="id">id_tec_pag</d>`. Ai voce pega esse id no jquery com o closest. `var row = $(this).closest('tr'); var id = row.find('.id').text()`

Comment: Qualquer modo me ajudaria, por exemplo, tenho um botão que adiciona uma div, e ele começa com um id de região =1, quero saber quantos id_tec_pag o usuário adicionou, quando ele adicionar outra região, no caso região = 2, quero saber quantos id_tec_pag tem na região 2 e assim por diante.

Comment: Como você adiciona esse item na tabela?

Comment: Estava adicionando apenas rows, mas sem diferenciar de qual é qual, com isso não consigo dar um UPDATE nas informações quando o usuário faz edição.

Comment: adiciona um data-id no campo e ai recupera o valor do data-id e soma para obter o n° do novo id.

Answer (score 0):

Para você recuperar a quantidade de linhas de sua tabela você pode utilizar

```
var numeroLinhas = document.getElementById('seuId').rows.length;
```

Se você deseja percorrer cada elemento da sua lista o jquery facilita:

```
$('#suaTabela > tbody  > tr').each(function() { //Sua regra de negócio });
```